# How to set text to a text view from a Thread class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ui-thread

I am reading a inputstream chunck by chunk and tryng to set read chunk to a textview from a Thread class but text is only getting printed after completion of while loop below is my code :

```
class SendFileThread  extends Thread 
{

    Handler mHandler;
    FileInputStream instream;

    SendFileThread(Handler h, FileInputStream stream )
    {
        mHandler = h;
        instream = stream;
        this.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
 final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        Message msg;
        byte [] usbdata = new byte[64];
         int readcount = 0;         
        sendByteCount = 0;
        int val = 0;

        if(instream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                readcount = instream.read(usbdata,0,64);
            }
            catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

            while(readcount > 0)
            {   

                    sendData(readcount, usbdata);
                    sendByteCount += readcount;
                try
                {
                    readcount = instream.read(usbdata,0,64);
                     if(readcount == -1){
                            pending = false;
                            //send_file = false;
                            setDefaultsBoo("pending",pending, J2xxHyperTerm.this);
                        }else{
                             result.append(new String(usbdata, 0, readcount));
                        }

                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                                 readText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                                    readText.setText(result.toString());
                                    //scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, readText.getHeight() + 30);

                        }
                    });

                }
                catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

            }
        }
            }
}
```

text is getting set to textview only after all the work is done.

Comment: Views can be touched by only the thread which creates it. TextView is created by main thread, so you can not update/change state from another thread(as in your case above).
However you can send an event from thread to use Handler/Looper.getMainLooper/RunOnUiThread(if in Activity context) , so that Main thread will update the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this method in your thread :

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       //update your textview
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

After work is done, try this -

```
Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, what, arg1, arg2, "text");
// what= some int identififer, lets say 1101
msg.sendToTarget();
```

in the listening activity implement `Handler.Callback`. You will have to implement `handleMessage`

```
@Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
case 1104: // the what identifier you set in  message
String text = (String) msg.obj;
textView.setText(text)
break;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AsyncTask for this use-case, as the ability to update views on the UI thread is included right out of the box.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

This is from the usage example provided, with comments to show you where the main thread action happens.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

     // Done in the background, on a separate thread
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

         int count = urls.length;

         long totalSize = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);

             // This part of the loop publishes the progress to onProgressUpdate(..)
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));

             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     // Called on the main thread whenever publishProgress(..) is called
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     // Also called on the main thread, after the background task is finished
     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an EventBus, to communicate between your thread to your activity.
[This](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is their github project. you can implement it and also enable communication between every Android app component. For example, like in your case, between thread and activity.